# Apache Airflow - connecting to AWS S3 error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow

I'm trying to get S3 hook in Apache Airflow using the Connection object.

It looks like this:

```
class S3ConnectionHandler:
    def __init__():
        # values are read from configuration class, which loads from env. variables
        self._s3 = Connection(
            conn_type="s3",
            conn_id=config.AWS_CONN_ID,
            login=config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            password=config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            extra=json.dumps({"region_name": config.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}),
        )

    @property
    def s3(self) -> Connection:
        return get_live_connection(self.logger, self._s3)

    @property
    def s3_hook(self) -> S3Hook:
        return self.s3.get_hook()
```

I get an error:

```
Broken DAG: [...] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/connection.py", line 282, in get_hook
    return hook_class(**{conn_id_param: self.conn_id})
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/base_aws.py", line 354, in __init__
    raise AirflowException('Either client_type or resource_type must be provided.')
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Either client_type or resource_type must be provided.
```

Why does this happen? From what I understand the S3Hook calls the constructor from the parent class, AwsHook, and passes the client_type as "s3" string. How can I fix this?

I took this configuration for hook from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66014947/creating-boto3-s3-client-on-airflow-with-an-s3-connection-and-s3-hook).

**EDIT:** I even get the same error when directly creating the S3 hook:

```
    @property
    def s3_hook(self) -> S3Hook:
        #return self.s3.get_hook()
        return S3Hook(
            aws_conn_id=config.AWS_CONN_ID,
            region_name=self.config.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,
            client_type="s3",
            config={"aws_access_key_id": self.config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, "aws_secret_access_key": self.config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
        )
``
```

Comment: I cannot replicate this locally, from what I see the S3Hook does `kwargs['client_type'] = 's3'` in the first line so the error should never occur. Which version of amazon provider do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No other answers worked, I couldn't get around this. I ended up using `boto3` library directly, which also gave me more low-level flexibility that Airflow hooks lacked.

Comment: can you please share how you used boto3?

Comment: @Explorer I basically just followed quickstart boto3 tutorials on downloading and uploading files: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-examples.html.

Answer (score 2):

If youre using Airflow 2
please refer to the new [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/base_aws/index.html) - it can be kind of tricky as most of the google searches redirect you to the old ones.

In my case I was using the `AwsHook` and had to switch to `AwsBaseHook` as it seems to be the only and correct one for version 2. I've had to switch the import path as well, now aws stuff isnt on `contrib` anymore its under `providers`

And as you can see on the new documentation you can pass either client_type ou  resource_type as a AwsBaseHook parameter, depending on the one you want to use. Once you do that your problem should be solved

Answer (score 0):

First of all , I suggest that you create a S3 connection , for this you must go the path **Admin >> Connections**

[image: S3 connection]

After that and assuming that you want to load a file into S3 Bucket,  you can code :

```
def load_csv_S3(): 
    
    # Send to S3
    
    hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id="s3_conn")
    hook.load_file(
        filename='/write_your_path_file/filename.csv',
        key='filename.csv',
        bucket_name="BUCKET_NAME",
        replace=True,
    )
```

Finally, you can check all the functions of ***S3Hook***  [HERE](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/s3.py)

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me, in case it helps someone, in my answer to a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73652781/4187360