# How do I create and pass a test conn_id to the S3_hook.S3Hook(conn_id) to debug a code in airflow DAG

Tags: python, amazon-s3, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a deployed DAG in which I'm using check_for_wildcard_key() to check if files for a particular day are present in an s3 location and then decide which branch to return.
following is the code :

```
from airflow.hooks import S3_hook
def checkforfiles(**kwargs):
    hook = S3_hook.S3Hook('s3_dummy')
    if hook.check_for_wildcard_key(f"s3://bucket/fixed/path/that/stays/the/same/daily/{sub_path_that_changes_daily}/*"):
        return 'branch1
    else:
        return 'end'
```

The problem is that even though the files are present at their locations, 'end' is returned all the time. I want to test what's happening here in my local system since there is virtually no useful logging in airflow.
I have the acees_key and secret_key for the bucket, how do I pass them to this s3_hook?
As of now I get the following error :

```
AirflowNotFoundException: The conn_id `s3_dummy` isn't defined
```

I tried using mock but couldn't figure out a way to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.
*Edit : Although I found the bug in my code without the need of a mock connection, but let's keep this thread open to help others in need.

Answer (score 0):

You are using deprecated import.
You need to import the hook from [Amazon provider](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/) as:

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook
```

The error means that you didn't define conn_id. You need to follow [this guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/connections/aws.html) and setup the connection. You can also check [creating boto3 s3 client on Airflow with an s3 connection and s3 hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66014947/creating-boto3-s3-client-on-airflow-with-an-s3-connection-and-s3-hook/66016466#66016466)
for refrence.

If you are looking to mock a connection you can for example do:

```
conn = Connection(
    conn_type="gcpssh",
    login="cat",
    host="conn-host",
)
conn_uri = conn.get_uri()
with mock.patch.dict("os.environ", AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_CONN=conn_uri):
    assert "cat" == Connection.get("my_conn").login
```

This is explained in the [Mocking variables and connections](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#mocking-variables-and-connections) section of Airflow docs.

You can see examples how to use `check_for_wildcard_key` in the [test file](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/27a80511ec3ffcf036354741bd0bfe18d4b4a471/tests/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/test_s3.py#L249-L269).

Comment: Thnakyou for the answer Elad, but I already went through all of these resources before coming here since none of these helped my case. As I mentioned in the question, I only have acees_key and secret_key to the bucket and do not have login or host values. passing them in "Extras" doesn't help either.

Comment: The guide says to place the access_key in the host and secret_key in the password. If that didn't work please clarify what is the issue